# OpenFeign ошибка при отправлении запроса

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Насмотрелся разных гайдов и документации, но так и не понял до конца, может кто подскажет, что нужно сделать для корректной работы.

Описание:
Необходимо отправить данный http-запрос
`https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/random?api_key=hidyT0yooJt3jmgfSpg9CsPge7xEEZq&tag=rich` и получить респонс.

Логика:
Контроллер принимаем в запросе некоторый параметр tag

```
@GetMapping("/gif")
public ResponseEntity getGifByCurrency(@RequestParam("tag") String tag){
    return gifService.getGif(tag);
}
```

Далее идет вызов сервиса, который к tag добавляет необходимый api_key для дальнейшей работы.

```
public ResponseEntity getGif(String tag) {
    return gifClient.getGif(API_KEY,tag);
}
```

Код Feign-client выглядит данным образом

```
@FeignClient(name = "gif-client", url = "https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs")
public interface GifClient {
     @GetMapping(value = "/random")
     ResponseEntity getGif(@RequestParam("api_key") String api_key, @RequestParam("tag") String tag);
}
```

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ 1.**

Сам запрос полностью рабочий через постман отрабатывает на ура. (Токен в данном вопросе немного изменен, у вас работать не должно, приведен в качестве примера)
Также при попытке вытащить респонс через мой feign-client выдает данную ошибку:

```
Parse Error: The response headers can't include "Content-Length" with chunked encoding
```

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ 2.**

Заголовки response при отправке чистого http-запроса через postman.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ 3.**

Заголовки, полученные из самой программы. (для удобства)

```
[GifClient#getGif] ---> GET https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/random?api_key=hidyT0yooJt3jmgfSpg9CsPge7xEEZq&tag=rich HTTP/1.1
[GifClient#getGif] ---> END HTTP (0-byte body)
[GifClient#getGif] <--- HTTP/1.1 200 OK (298ms)
[GifClient#getGif] accept-ranges: bytes
[GifClient#getGif] access-control-allow-credentials: true
[GifClient#getGif] access-control-allow-headers: Authorization, Content-Type, Accept, x-requested-with, cache-control, X-GIPHY-SDK-NAME, X-GIPHY-SDK-VERSION, X-GIPHY-SDK-PLATFORM
[GifClient#getGif] access-control-allow-methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
[GifClient#getGif] access-control-allow-origin: *
[GifClient#getGif] connection: keep-alive
[GifClient#getGif] content-type: application/json
[GifClient#getGif] date: Mon, 22 Feb 2021 16:46:38 GMT
[GifClient#getGif] strict-transport-security: max-age=86400
[GifClient#getGif] transfer-encoding: chunked
[GifClient#getGif] vary: Accept-Encoding
[GifClient#getGif] x-cache-hits: 0, 0
[GifClient#getGif] x-cachiness-edge-actual-ttl: 120.000
[GifClient#getGif] x-cachiness-edge-rule: giphy_api_vcl_fetch_stale_if_error_val_set
[GifClient#getGif] x-cachiness-shield-actual-ttl: 120.000
[GifClient#getGif] x-cachiness-shield-rule: giphy_api_vcl_fetch_stale_if_error_val_set
[GifClient#getGif] x-robots-tag: noindex
[GifClient#getGif] x-rule-debug: 1
[GifClient#getGif] x-served-by: cache-bwi5126-BWI, cache-fra19140-FRA
[GifClient#getGif] x-timer: S1614012398.160964,VS0,VE162
[GifClient#getGif] <--- END HTTP (9498-byte body)
```

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ 4.**

Благодаря Роману и подключению логгера на feign-client также выяснил, что тело запроса, некоторая {data} успешно приходит
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @RomanKonoval дополнил вопрос, ошибка в получении самого респонса.

Comment: Действительно ли сервер возвращает результат с заголовками `Content-Length` и `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`? Посмотрите это включив лог https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-feign.html#_feign_logging

Comment: @RomanKonoval заголовки response продемонстрировал. Через само приложение вылетает:
Could not get response.

Comment: Это вы показали из postman-a, где все работает, а нужно из программы, где не работает :)

Comment: Лучше всего сравнить и запросы, которые посылаются. И ответы, которые приходят. Для этого хорошо использовать утилиту https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat. Запустить ее локально `nc -k -l 10000` и заменить URL на `http://localhost:10000`

Comment: @RomanKonoval полученные заголовки из приложения выложил

Comment: Еще для полноты картины не хватает стектрейса. А вообще, если ругается на `Content-Length`, а в ответе его нет, то остается только ставить breakpoint на исключение, которое возникает (возникает же? а то из вопроса не понятно) и смотреть в исходниках, почему feign считает что `Content-Length` есть. Обычно в спринге не проблема увидеть (с feigh конкретно не работал, может там все хуже).

Comment: @RomanKonoval к сожалению никаких исключений не возникает и приложение не падает, по крайне мере я не оборачиваю ни одну строчку в try-catch, а при отправке запроса в консоле ни одного мессаджа по этому поводу.

Comment: Почему тогда решили, что проблема в `gifClient.getGif`? Что возвращает метод?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решается тем, что методу getGif необходимо возвращать

```
ResponseEntity<?>
```

Вместо

```
ResponseEntity
```

Итоговый вид GifClient:

```
 @FeignClient(name = "gif-client", url = "https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs")
 public interface GifClient {
     @GetMapping(value = "/random")
     ResponseEntity<?> getGif(@RequestParam("api_key") String api_key, @RequestParam("tag") String tag);
 }
```

Wildcard нужны для тех случаев, если мы не имеем представления о том, что приходит, поэтому я создал некоторое DTO:

```
public class GifDTO {
   private String url;
}
```

И теперь можно получать конкретный response:

```
@FeignClient(name = "gif-client", url = "https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs")
 public interface GifClient {
     @GetMapping(value = "/random")
     ResponseEntity<GifDTO> getGif(@RequestParam("api_key") String api_key, @RequestParam("tag") String tag);
 }
```